# Convergence of $\sum x_k \log (x_k^{-1}) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove or disprove: If $\{x_k\} \subset (0,1)$, and $\sum x_k < \infty$, then $\sum x_k \log (x_k^{-1}) < \infty$.

What if $\{x_k\}$ is monotone? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does $\log(x^{k})^{-1}$ mean $\frac{1}{\log(x_{k})}$ or $\log(\frac{1}{x_{k}})$??

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is the latter. Edited.

Comment: If you take a sequence $(x_k)$ such that $\sum x_k$ just barely converges, do you expect that $\sum x_k\log (x_k^{-1})$ would converge too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $x_n = \frac{1}{n(\log n)^r}$ for $r>0$. Then

$$x_n \log x_n^{-1} = \frac{1}{n(\log n)^r} \log(n\log(n)^r)) > \frac{1}{n(\log n)^{r-1}}$$

The integral test can be used to find the range of $r$ for which the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)^r}$ converges.